# Can I use IntelliSense for linux system like arpa in vscode on windows?

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed Linux on WSL.
I make a c file in the `mnt/` folder.
I installed vs code and c/c++ extension, WSL extention.
And then reconfigured IntelliSense for the GCC compiler.

but VS Code doesn't recommend line for Linux like `arpa/inet.h`, `sys/socket.h`.

What can I do for it?

How to configure vscode intelligence for linux on windows?

Comment: My question is stupid. I can connect to ubuntu in WSL with vscode instead just open windows folders(/mnt/c...). And then everything is well.

Comment: Hey! I 

I'm having some Intellisense red squiggles for include header files that are only for Linux, and I think I'm having the same issue as this. How did you resolve it by "connect to Ubuntu in WSL in VScode?" I was able to get WSL running in the VSCode terminal by installing and typing wsl in the terminal inside of VSCode, but I'm not sure how this is supposed to apply to Intellisense

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can use code intelligence in vs code for linux as well, try pressing 'Ctrl + Space' to toggle intellisense
alternatively if you dont want to have intellisense ON all the time, you can press 'Tab' whenever you do want suggestions for the current line of code..

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).